# Dúvidas a respeito de classes e atributos em python

Tags: python

Estou criando um programa em python e estou com algumas dúvidas a respeito da declaração de classes e atributos.

Eu tenho dois arquivos de classes, um chamado geradadosps.py e outra kpi.py

Dentro desses arquivos, eu tenho as classes Geradados e Kpi A classe Geradados importa os atributos da classe Kpi.

```
import random

#import numpy

from kpi import Kpi

class Geradadosps:

def __init__(self,nome_arquivo,identificador,habilidade):
    self.nome_arquivo = nome_arquivo
    self.identificador = identificador
    self.habilidade = habilidade
    self.qnt_historicos = 10
    self.qnt_kpi = 4
    self.kpi
pass

def Gerar_historico(self,kpi_identificador):
    kpi_historico = []
    for i in range(self.qnt_historico):
        kpi_historico = kpi.historico.append(round(random.random(),2))
    self.kpi = Kpi(kpi_identificador,kpi_historico)
```

A minha pergunta é. Como eu atribuo o objeto kpi pra dentro do atributo self.kpi da classe geradadosps?

Está certa essa atribuição?

Informações da classe kpi.py

```
class Kpi:

def __init__(self,identificador, historico):
    self.identificador = identificador
    self.qnt_historicos = 10
    self.historico = historico
pass

@property
def historico(self):
     return self._historico

@historico.setter
def historico(self, historico):
     self._historico= historico
```